# Given symmetry of metric tensor, can't all the partial derivatives in the Christoffel symbols be reduced to just one?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

The Christoffel symbols of the first kind:

$$\Gamma_{mij}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \sum_j\left( \frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x_j}- \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_m}\right)$$

In my very imperfect understanding of this subject, the first two partial derivatives of the metric tensor on the RHS are equal because the metric tensor is symmetric.

$$\frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x_j}$$

Q1: Appreciate if someone could offer some intuitive explanation of this mathematical fact (assuming I am correct in saying it is a fact). It's easy to see that $\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_m}=\frac{\partial g_{ji}}{\partial x_m}$, but I have a hard time wrapping my head around symmetry between indices in the numerator and denominator of the partial derivative.

Q2: If the displayed equality is true, then it must also be true that the last partial derivative in the Christoffel symbols of the first kind could be expressed:

$$\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_m}=\frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x_j}$$

and so why don't we just write the Christoffel symbols of the first kind much more simply as:

$$\Gamma_{mij}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \sum_j\frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x_i}$$

?

By the way, I read that the second displayed equation is a mathematical fact on pg. 13 of "Introduction to General Relativity" by Walecka, 2007. Perhaps I have misunderstood Walecka?

Comment: $\frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x_i}\color{red}{\neq}\frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x_j}$

Comment: You can exchange the indices on the metric, not between the metric and the derivatives.

Comment: @Javier Yeah, I didn't think so, but then I read Walecka. Guess I'm not getting what he's saying.

Comment: Walecka exchanges the names of the summation indices $j$ and $k$ and uses that $\frac{dq^j}{dt} \frac{dq^k}{dt} = \frac{dq^k}{dt} \frac{dq^j}{dt}$.